# Solving Differential equations second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve this second order differential equation?
$$(M−1000\, t)y'' + ky' = T_0\sinαt−\frac{M−1000\, t}{r−y}$$

I am familiar somewhat with solving the second order differential equation, however the reciprocal function on the other hand of the equality seems to be the trouble. A post made earlier does suggest that it has no closed form solution in general, but however I was just curious.